# Excel VBA Script for moving data from one sheet to another without overwriting compile errors.

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code. I keep getting various errors and have scoured the forums trying to find an answer, but I cant get it to compile. Current error is "Sub or Function undefined" I'm trying to copy all data other than headers from sheet DailyInput to the end of sheet MonthlyRoll without overriding data in MonthlyRoll. This would be controlled by command button, but I cant even get it to compile.  I'm fairly new to VBA, and just can't figure out my error. I'm using Excel2016.

```
Sub copycolumns()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Worksheet("DailyInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Worksheet("DailyInput").Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Worksheet("DailyInput").PasteDestination:=Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Cells(erow, 1)

Worksheet("DailyInput").Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheet("DailyInput").PasteDestination:=Worksheets(“MonthlyRoll”).Cells(erow, 2)

Worksheet("DailyInput").Cells(i, 6).Copy
Worksheet("DailyInput").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Cells(erow, 3)
End If

Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheet("MonthlyRoll").Columns().AutoFit
Range(“A1”).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You have an `End if` without and `If`. This is where indenting your code would help out a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, get in the habit of using "Option Explicit" at the top of your module.  This will help A LOT!

One of your problems is you're trying to use Worksheet, which isn't a valid VBA object. Also, you're missing a space in your .Paste code.  This compiles, see if it gives you the expected results.

```
 Sub copycolumns()
Dim i As Long, _
    lastRow As Long, _
    erow As Long

lastRow = Worksheets("DailyInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Worksheets("DailyInput").Cells(i, 1).Copy
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("DailyInput").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Cells(erow, 1)

    Worksheets("DailyInput").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Worksheets("DailyInput").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Cells(erow, 2)

    Worksheets("DailyInput").Cells(i, 6).Copy
    Worksheets("DailyInput").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Cells(erow, 3)
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("MonthlyRoll").Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```